# Can I ignore getting end-of-file in C?

Tags: c, eof

I am trying to make a program that asks a user for input. I already know how to terminate the program after getting EOF.

```
if(feof(stdin)) exit(1);
```

Or,

```
while(!feof(stdin)) { ... }
```

By ignoring I mean that the program does nothing after catching EOF. Like signal handling:

```
signal(SIGTERM, no_op_function);
```

Comment: Note that [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/15168)

Comment: You may need to use `clearerr(stdin)` to continue after getting EOF.

Comment: You should also note that there's a difference between ignoring a signal (`signal(SIGTERM, SIG_IGN)`) and setting a function that does nothing to handle the signal.

Comment: If you want to continue after `EOF`, then do so. You don't need to `exit()`. However, if `stdin` returns `EOF`, there will be no more to read.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's what worked for me:

```
clearerr(stdin);
```

Thanks to @JonathanLeffler for the answer.